# Anonymous stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In Oracle, we can write anonymous blocks for quick testing of logic without having to store the object on the database.

Does SQL Server support anonymous blocks? I tried google, but it mostly returns links for oracle.

Comment: For of all those poor souls who don't know Oracle that well - can you briefly explain what an "anonymous procedure" in Oracle is?

Comment: as I mentioned in my post, I do not want to store the object in the database. I can write all the logic in anonymous block as I would in a stored procedure, except anonymous block does not get stored on the database. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use SSMS to test any "block" of T-SQL without creating any sort of object (stored procedure or function). Just declare your variables, if you need any, and wirte your code.

For example if this is the stored you want to test

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [MySchema].[proc_modifySomething]
      @ID int
    , @Language char(2) = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ITEMTYPE_EVENT varchar(2)      = 'J';  
    DECLARE @CURRENTDATE datetime           = GETDATE();
```

You should instead write:

```
DECLARE
      @ID int
    , @Language char(2) = NULL
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ITEMTYPE_EVENT varchar(2)      = 'J';  
    DECLARE @CURRENTDATE datetime           = GETDATE();
```

Comment: How? Which is the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't.

Sample Oracle anonymous proc :

```
declare
  procedure p
  as
  begin
    select 'p' from dual;
  end;
begin
  p;
end;
```